# Use of do–while loop to perform the operation as many times as user want

Tags: c++

I'm developing a program in C++ that calculate the factorial of a given number. Use for loop to calculate the factorial & do–while loop to perform the operation as many times as user want

I wrote a code for factorial with for loop But not able that how I use Do while loop for performing
The code is following

```
int n;
int factorial = 1;

cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
cin >> n;

for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i)
{
     factorial *= i;   // factorial = factorial * i;
}

cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial;
```

Please help me.

Comment: The factorial doesn't matter (but keep an eye on that loop, it looks off by one). Try to figure out the logic of the do-while first. Just try out different things, you can't really break anything.

Comment: Do you have any examples from class notes that show how to ask a user if they want to continue or perform an operation again or if they want to quit?

Comment: Change the `for` loop into a `do`-`while` loop.   Read any basic text for information on how to structure a `do`-`while` loop.   Also, calculation of a factorial will overflow a 32-bit `int` for a value of 13 or more, or overflow a 64-bit int for a value of 21 or more.   If you want the user to be able to enter arbitrary values, you need to use a big integer library of some form - and that is non-standard.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com, @Peter.

Comment: Hi @Faisal and welcome to Stackoverflow. Actually this website a Q&A website and usually we ask questions which contain exact details and the exact problem we face. That's the reason you are getting downvotes. We have posted some answers below, please take a look, but **please** next time take a look at these resources for asking better questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ; [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Guys please pay attention to the "New contributor" icon below the user name. And be more welcoming to the new members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string answer;

    do {
        int n;
        int factorial = 1;

        cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
        cin >> n;

        for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i)
        {
            factorial *= i;   // factorial = factorial * i;
        }

        cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to do again? (type 'n' for No, anything for yes)"  << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        cin.clear(); // Clearing the cin buffer

    } while (answer != "n");

    cout << "Exitting"  << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

**Update** (according to the request in the comment)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counter=0, amount;

    cout << "How many times : ";
    cin>> amount;

    do {
        int n;
        int factorial = 1;

        cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
        cin >> n;

        for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i)
        {
            factorial *= i;   // factorial = factorial * i;
        }

        cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial << endl;

        counter++;

    } while (counter < amount);

    cout << "Completed"  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its working but one more thing if i want that before running factorial portion it ask me about yes or no like in this first time it run wdout asking

Comment: Your welcome!, I have updated the answer and added full version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic using do-while loop.

```
    int count =0, f=1, times, n;

    cout << "Enter how many times : ";
    cin>> times
    cout << "\n Enter number for which you want to calculate factorial : ";
    cin>> n

  do{
        for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
            f *= i;
        }
        cout<< "Factorial of n is : " << f;
        cout << "\n Enter next number for which you want to calculate factorial : ";
        cin>> n
        f = 1;
        count++;
    }while(count <= times);
```

Comment: Got it!!, I missed it, edited the answer. And Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Alright with some changes it is working Right now Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for times = 1, you should use `<=` instead of `!=` and `count` should start at 0, else you loop one time less than required.